# How to replace html tags while writing web scraper in C#?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, web-crawler, console-application

I am writing console application for web crawling and scraping in C# just for learning purpose only. When result is displayed, some of the values are displayed along with the html tags, infact  tags. I figured out the strong tags and replaced them completely. But what if there were many strong tags with different inline styling values? 
How could I solve this problem ?

Well the problem is in GetData() function

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace MyCrawler
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static string GetContent(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string line = "";
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                builder.Append(line.Trim());
            }
            reader.Close();
            return builder.ToString().Replace("\n", "");
        }

      public static void GetData(string content)
        {
          // these tags are to be replaced 
            string ToBeReplaced1 = "<strong style=\"color:#F00\">";   // 
            string ToBeReplaced2 = "</strong>";
            string ToBeReplaced3 = "<strong style=\"color:#000099\">";

          // pattern for regular expression
            string pattern3 = "<dt>(.*?)</dt><dd>(.*?)</dd>";

            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern3);
            MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches(content);

            foreach(Match m2 in mc)
            {
                Console.Write(m2.Groups[1].Value);
                Console.WriteLine(((m2.Groups[2].Value.Replace(ToBeReplaced3, "")).Replace(ToBeReplaced1, "")).Replace(ToBeReplaced2, ""));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();         
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://www.merojob.com/";
            string content = GetContent(url);

            string pattern = "<div class=\"employername\"><h2>(.*?)</h2><a href=\"(.*?)\"";

            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
            MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches(content);

            foreach (Match m in mc)
            {
                foreach (Capture c in m.Groups[2].Captures)
                {                   
                    //Console.WriteLine(c.Value); // write the value to the console "pattern"
                    content = GetContent(c.Value);
                   GetData(content);
                }
            }       
            Console.ReadKey();            
        }
    }
}
```

Well, if I dont use Replace() function, I end up with :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best way in your case would be to use a dedicated library, such as [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to be able to retrieve specific tags and manipulate the structure of your DOM document. Doing it manually is a recipe for pain. Doing it with regular expressions may [endanger your mind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) so use a library to handle your html

Even if this is for learning purposes only, you are not really using the right tool or exercice to start learning, since this is a really complicated subject.